# python3 pip broken since system update

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, pip, ubuntu-16.04

After updating one of my Ubuntu 16.04 machines on AWS, python/pip appears to be broken.

```
ubuntu@host:~$ pip install celery
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/virtualenvs/myenv/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
    from pip import main
  File "/home/ubuntu/virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
    from pip.utils import get_installed_distributions, get_prog
  File "/home/ubuntu/virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from pip.locations import (
  File "/home/ubuntu/virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/locations.py", line 9, in <module>
    from distutils import sysconfig
  File "/home/ubuntu/virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.6/distutils/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from distutils import dist, sysconfig
ImportError: cannot import name 'dist'

ubuntu@host:~$ python3.6 -m pip install celery
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 183, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 142, in _get_module_details
    return _get_module_details(pkg_main_name, error)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 109, in _get_module_details
    __import__(pkg_name)
  File "/home/ubuntu/virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
    from pip.utils import get_installed_distributions, get_prog
  File "/home/ubuntu/virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from pip.locations import (
  File "/home/ubuntu/virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/locations.py", line 9, in <module>
    from distutils import sysconfig
  File "/home/ubuntu/virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.6/distutils/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from distutils import dist, sysconfig
ImportError: cannot import name 'dist'
```

The system runs python3.6 installed through the `jonathonf/python-3.6` ppa. Before the system update (`apt-get update && apt-get upgrade`) everything worked as expected. I also verified this on other machines I have not updated yet.

I have also had no luck installing python3.6 in a virtual environment on a fresh machine, so I guess a recent release or update broke something here?

---

edit:

I am also running into similar problems when installing on a fresh ubuntu:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
$ sudo add-apt-repository jonathonf/python-3.6
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install python3.6

$ stat /usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py
stat: cannot stat '/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py': No such file or directory

$ ll /usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/
total 36
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 May  3 15:55 ./
drwxr-xr-x 28 root root 12288 May  3 15:44 ../
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   236 May  3 11:50 __init__.py
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 12345 May  3 11:50 version.py

$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
```

Comment: It's strange that the call stack switched to a virtual env - what is the output of `pip -V` and your `PATH`? If the `/home/ubuntu/virtualenvs/myenv/` dir is in the `PATH`, try removing it.

Comment: `pip -v` yields the same error as above. I am executing the commands from within the virtualenv, so removing its path from `PATH` defaults back to the system defaults (python3 outside venv, python2.7 pip).

Comment: oh, I see. Can you verify the file `/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py` exists? If yes, then my guess is that you have another `distutils` module with same name in the `sys.path` that is found before the correct one, causing the error.

Comment: `/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py` does not exist. The `dist.py` appears to be missing in both the global and the virtualenv `site-packages`.

Comment: Looks like your recent update borked the `python3.6` installation, try reinstalling it. The `dist.py` shouldn't be available in a venv, this is correct. Instead, a venv provides a bootstrap script (`path/to/venv/lib/python3.6/distutils/__init__.py`) that imports all the necessary `distutils` stuff from the main installation.

Comment: I just set up another machine and installed python3.6. The issue is still the same, the `dist.py` is missing. I edited the post to include my installation steps, is there anything wrong with what I am doing there?

Comment: This also seems to affect Linux Mint 18.3 after a `sudo apt-get upgrade`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've tested the PPA in a fresh docker container and it looks like the package is broken, all `distutils` modules are missing after installation. Looks like the package was rebuilt recently; maybe this is a new issue.

[You can open a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/~jonathonf) and wait until the PPA maintainer fixes it, but aside from that, there's not much you can do. You can of course try fiddling the installation:

```bash
$ wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.5/Python-3.6.5.tgz
$ tar xvf Python-3.6.5.tgz
$ rsync -av Python-3.6.5/Lib/distutils/ /usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/
```

Of course, this is a very dirty stuff because I don't know what files should the correct package from that PPA have. Thus, I can give you no guarantee whatsoever whether this will work for you and not introduce any new bugs, but at least I could get `pip` running again and could install a package.

Comment: Thank you for confirming that I am not actually going crazy. I just switched to another ppa (`deadsnakes/ppa`) and everything appears to be working again.

Answer (score 3):

This solves the problem for me on Ubuntu and Linux Mint. First confirm that `python3.6` is installed through `ppa:jonathonf/python-3.6` by running the commands:

```
ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d
sudo rm -i /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jonathonf-python-3_6-xenial.list
```

Then add the `deadsnakes` PPA using:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt-get update
```

And finally either remove/install or reinstall `python3.6`

```
sudo apt-get remove python3.6
sudo apt-get install python3.6
```

I also ran into unmet dependencies when reinstalling python. This was solved by manually removing `libpython3.6-minimal`. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

You're indeed not crazy, same problem here.

You can also try a previous version of the ppa from the same ppa, until they fix it:
https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf/+archive/ubuntu/python-3.6

example command line is:

```
apt-get install python3.6=3.6.3-1ubuntu1~17.04.york1
```

Answer (score 0):

run

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install -f && sudo apt upgrade
```

`sudo apt-get install python3.6`

to overcome broken installation

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
# dpkg -l | grep python3.5
```

You will get a list of dependencies, add them all to the end of this line:

```
# apt-get --purge remove <here>
```

Now run this:

```
# apt-get install python3.5-dev
```

Here is a link to a nice article: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-change-from-default-to-alternative-python-version-on-debian-linux

Comment: (3.5 is probably where you did damage, it is deeply woven into 16.04)

Answer (score 0):

I've just upgraded to disco dingo (19.04), and it broke my python3.6, with the following error message :

```
tox -e py36 --recreate                
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pierre/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 22, in <module>
    import distutils.spawn
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.spawn'
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python3.6
```

You can switch to Python 3.7 which seem to be the new default: `tox -e py37` runs correctly.