# pip error on running pip freeze

Tags: django, python-3.x, pip

I made a registration system with Django using celery, redis. It was working fine till today. But getting this error 'Redis is not install' when try to register a new user. I was trying to check packages installed using pip and getting this.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/chhuti/projects/venv/chhuti/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
  from pip import main
  File "/home/chhuti/projects/venv/chhuti/lib/python3.6/site- 
     packages/pip/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
     from pip.utils import get_installed_distributions, get_prog
  File "/home/chhuti/projects/venv/chhuti/lib/python3.6/site- 
     packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
     from pip.locations import (
  File "/home/chhuti/projects/venv/chhuti/lib/python3.6/site- 
     packages/pip/locations.py", line 9, in <module>
     from distutils import sysconfig
  File 
  "/home/chhuti/projects/venv/chhuti/lib/python3.6/distutils/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
     from distutils import dist, sysconfig
     ImportError: cannot import name 'dist'
```

I am using 
pip version 9.0.2, 
Python version 3.6.3
Django 1.11
Have been stuck here for a long time now, couldn't solve it.

Comment: You'll need to specify versions of everything. Python, pip, setuptools, anything else relevant.

Comment: What did you run to check installed packages?

Comment: I have versions of python, pip, But couldn't get the version of setuptools as I am getting the same error. @jpmc26

Comment: In my registration system I have used celery and redis. But When I am trying to register getting this error redos is not installed(Which is installed). I needed to check packages install using pip freeze. N.B it worked perfectly fine till yesterday. @SK.FazleeRabby

Comment: You can get the setuptools version from `easy_install --version`.

Comment: getting the same error, I have mentioned above when I try to run easy_install --version

Comment: I would try reinstalling setuptools, then, with the latest version. Then I'd upgrade pip. If that didn't work, I'd wipe the entire Python install and start from scratch. You do have your required packages listed in some other form, right (a requirements.txt or a pipenv file or something)?

Comment: I wiped entire python 3.6 already and will check now if it works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python3 pip broken since system update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50157653/python3-pip-broken-since-system-update)